# Manually replace missing value in a column based on another column

Tags: r

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
geo     mark     value
texas   nissan   2 
texas   nissan   78
ny      NA       65
ny      NA       15
ca      audi     22
```

I want to manually replace the `NA` in the column `mark` based on the `geo` column. So, in the example above, for every row of `geo` called 'ny' I want to insert 'toyota', like this:

```
geo     mark     value
texas   nissan   2 
texas   nissan   78
ny      toyota   65
ny      toyota   15
ca      audi     22
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work. Not sure if in your data you'd have `NA` for all values of `geo == ny`. Hence I've added `& is.na(mark)`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(mark = case_when(geo == 'ny' & is.na(mark) ~ 'toyota', TRUE ~ mark))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  geo   mark   value
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
1 texas nissan     2
2 texas nissan    78
3 ny    toyota    65
4 ny    toyota    15
5 ca    audi      22
```

Comment: You could also replace the last condition (`TRUE ~ mark`) with `TRUE ~ replace_na(mark, "some_default")` if you want no leftover NA values